# Control row-level distribution in CockroachDB?

Tags: cockroachdb

If I know that one set of rows of my table receives a large amount of the traffic, can I partition that row to be on its own server so it doesn’t impact access to the rest of my table?

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB doesn't currently offer row-level control of data distribution, but we're working on implementing the feature in the near future.